# What is wrong with my simple prolog recursion?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog. Trying to write a predicate named `leaftree`, that is True if the given tree is a leaf tree. A tree is a leaf tree if all its leaves are atoms, or if it's empty. There's my predicate:

```
leaftree(nil).
leaftree(t(nil, X, nil)):-
    atom(X).
leaftree(t(L, X, R)):-  
    leaftree(L), leaftree(R).
```

There's the input I'm using to test this predicate:

```
leaftree(t(t(nil, 5, nil), X, nil)).
```

Well, the output is True but it should be False because 5 isn't an atom. I played around with the `leaftree(t(nil, X, nil)):- atom(X)` part; it seems like the predicate is called, but it always returns True. Even if I explicitly write `fail` or other false statements. If matters, I'm using [Swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). I'd love your thoughts!

Thanks so much in advance. Orel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your input is true because it matches the third definition of the predicate. So it exists a predicate that is true for your query.

This happens because in the third definition X is free to be anything. When consulting your file with swi-prolog i receive, in fact, a warning saying: Singleton variable [X].

You could replace the second and the third definition with the following (which include both)

```
leaftree(t(L, X, R)):-  
    leaftree(L), atom(X), leaftree(R).
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I uncovered the problem thanks to your comment.

Since nodes that aren't leaves don't have to be atoms, I sense that I should still use two different predicates. I added a `!` and replaced the singleton variable `X`, and now it works perfectly:

```
leaftree(nil).
leaftree(t(nil, X, nil)):-
    !, atom(X).
leaftree(t(L, _, R)):-  
    leaftree(L), leaftree(R).
```

Thanks A lot!
Orel

Comment: If Lospix's answer fully addressed your question, please make it the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it! This is helpful for both future readers as well as the person that answered your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!